# ¿Como reciclar código entre proyectos pero que se puedan seguir actualizando y sincronizar entre varios equipos?

Tags: java

Tengo unas clases en las que he estado trabajando y me gustaría usarlas para otros proyectos, pero también quiero seguir añadiendo nuevas operaciones y que estén disponibles para todos los proyectos. No entiendo muy bien los conceptos de esta manera de trabajar. Se que se pueden hacer librerías pero para esto es necesario estar agregándolas a cada proyecto y quisiera que estuvieran disponibles siempre para todos los proyectos. El problema más grave es que suelo usar diferentes equipos. En mi trabajo tengo uno, en mi casa un portátil y una de escritorio y para sincronizar los proyectos utilizo mega. Esto me da muchos problemas a la hora de trabajar con librerías puesto que tengo que actualizar las rutas cada vez.

¿Alguna sugerencia de como trabajar? Utilizo net beans y he escuchado que algo puede hacerse, pero no se como buscar información sobre estas capacidades. Un amigo mío me comentaba sobre un servidor de versiones y GitHub pero es un mundo completamente extraño para mi. Intente instalar Git pero no supe como utilizarlo ni de cerca.

Estoy atento a recomendaciones sobre cambiar la manera de trabajar. Gracias.

Comment: Si mi repuesta te ha sido de utilidad puedes marcarla como mejor respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un sistema de control de versiones y crear un repositorio en el que almacenaras todas tu librerías. Eso te ayudara a que puedas actualizar tu código y tener acceso a el desde  cualquier ordenador.

Prueba con: **Git** o **Github**. Yo utilizo estos. 
Si programas en visual studio, tienes varias opciones: **Visual Studio Team Services**, (Git y Github) instalando extensiones.

Para incluir las liberáis de forma automática en cada proyecto eso dependerá del entrono de desarrollo que utilices. Por lo generar yo utilizo **code snippets**.